# Write string with encoding of UTF-8 to a file

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I have a string in Ruby (v1.9.2) that is encoded in UTF-8. I check this via the string and per character:

```
enc = __ENCODING__
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

s.encoding 
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>

s.each_char{|c| return false unless c.encoding == enc }
# this passes
```

I take the string and write it to a file:

```
File.open("/path/to/file.rb", "w:UTF-8") do |f|
  f.write s
end
# => 39939

File.open("/path/to/file.rb", "rb").read.encoding
# => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

File.open("/path/to/file.rb", "r").read.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

The file is also set by the text editor I'm using (TextWrangler) to use UTF-8, and it has the magic comment set too. **How can I ensure any ruby program (not necessarily under my control) reading this file thinks the encoding is UTF-8?**

*Note: I do have a specific error I'm trying to fix, but this problem comes up enough that I'd like to have a general answer.*

Comment: only the Ruby interpreter or other Ruby libs using the file to be aware of what the encoding is when it reads in the file (which is code itself). OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Ruby takes the `$LANG` env variable as a starter, if that one is set to utf-8, ruby should read files as utf-8 by default.